# what page type should be used for Atlassian Confluence for a node vs. file with contents?

Tags: confluence

I want to create a "node" that will hold initially-blank pages below it, each representing a readme for a repo/codebase.  I could create a blank page and that would work but is there a better way?  There is no need for content in this particular node, the pages below themselves tell the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "Documentation" space template - it adds "Children pages" automatically to the bottom of each page.
Or use "Parent page" template - same functionality in *any* space type.